# Eliminar elemento de lista DE recursivamente

Tags: c

Tengo que borrar los elementos recursivamente de una lista doblemente enlazada del último al primero. Además, tiene un puntero al principio y otro al final.  No sé cuál es el error.

```
void eliminar (lista DE, PPF){
  if (DE==NULL)
    return DE;
  else{
    lista temp = ppf.ultimo;
    ppf.ultimo = ppf.ultimo-> anterior;
    delete temp;
    return eliminar (temp, PPF);
  }
}
```

Comment: He revertido los cambios porque los mismos colisionan con la respuesta que hay actualmente. Además cambian la etiqueta del lenguaje sin haber confirmado si el código se refiere a C o a C++ (que tenga `delete` no implica que el OP esté programando en C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin tener más código el problema está en que la llamada recursiva usa `temp`, elemento que acabas de borrar en vez de usar `ppf`.

```
void eliminar (lista DE, PPF){
  if (DE==NULL)
    return DE;
  else{
    lista temp = ppf.ultimo;
    ppf.ultimo = ppf.ultimo-> anterior;
    delete temp;                  // <<--- BORRAS temp
    return eliminar (temp, PPF);  // <<--- USAS temp
  }
}
```

El código corregido quedaría así:

```
void eliminar (lista DE, PPF){
  if (DE==NULL)
    return DE;
  else{
    lista temp = ppf.ultimo;
    ppf.ultimo = ppf.ultimo-> anterior;
    delete temp;
    return eliminar (ppf, PPF); // <<--- USAS ppf
  }
}
```

Por otro lado no termino de entender la utilidad de `PPF`. Es una variable que no usas para nada.

Adicionalmente:

- Te sugiero encarecidamente usar una nomenclatura más natural para las variables. No te haces ningún favor usando variables con nombres crípticos.
- No es lo mismo un nodo que una lista. Te sugiero separar ambos conceptos en estructuras / clases independientes. El código resultante será más natural e intuitivo.
- Para futuras preguntas (incluyendo esta si las respuestas no te sirven), incluye también la declaración de tipos y clases involucradas directamente en el código que falla.
- Presta atención al etiquetar las preguntas. `delete` **es de C++** no de C. Si etiquetas mal una pregunta puede acabar cerrada o sin respuestas (llegados a este punto te sugeriría confirmar si la pregunta está bien etiquetada)

Answer (score 0):

@Adri. Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta, porque `delete` no es un operador de C. Sospecho que esto es C++.

Asimismo, también te recomiendo usar llaves en todas las sentencias `if/else`. Del mismo modo, nos falta saber cómo has definido una `lista`, porque por ciencia infusa no voy a averiguar qué tipo de dato es `ultimo`, qué es `anterior`, ni nada.

Echándole un vistazo sin saber más del código, si haces `delete temp` y luego llamas a `eliminar(temp, ppf)`, obviamente estarás enviando un puntero a NULL.

Para colmo del remate, el parámetro `lista DE` lo pasas por copia, por lo que al borrar, nunca borras el elemento, borras la copia del elemento.

Comment: Yo lo tengo claro, @Adri creo que no lo tiene tan claro.
También es hartamente recomendado no hacer alias de tipos en C++, sino usar abiertamente autos para tal fin, o templates.

Quien se pone a hacer `typedef Lista plista*;` al final no sabe qué está haciendo

Comment: Sobraría si no fuera porque hace un `delete`, y el autor desconoce si borra el original, o no. Como se dice en algunos libros "eso es trabajo del lector". :)